# How to group by pandas with first occurance as primary

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv below

```
ID,PR_No,PMO,PRO,REV,COST
111,111,AB,MA,2575,2575
111,111,LL,NN,-1137,-1137
112,112,CD,KB,1134,3334
111,111,ZZ,YY,100,100
```

My Expected Output as below

```
ID,PR_No,PMO,PRO,REV,COST
111,111,AB,MA,1538,1538
112,112,CD,KB,1134,3334
```

For ID 111 there are so many PMO,PRO, but in the output we need to paste only first that is AB,MA occurrence.

What is the modification has to do for the code below

`df_n = df.groupby(['ID','PR_No','PMO','PRO'])['REV','COST'].sum()`

Or do i need to df.groupby(['ID','PR_No'])['REV','COST'].sum() later will be doing the mapping?

Comment: What if there are no occurrences? You keep all? As in 112?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by first 2 columns with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for next 2 columns:

```
d = {'PMO':'first','PRO':'first','REV':'sum','COST':'sum'}
df_n = df.groupby(['ID','PR_No'], as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df_n)
    ID  PR_No PMO PRO   REV  COST
0  111    111  AB  MA  1538  1538
1  112    112  CD  KB  1134  3334
```

Comment: can we insert PMO, PRO